# Animation swingworker threading and timer

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, graph

I must animate two graphs.  Both graphs are related.
One graph display cartography of colour, and the other is diplaying a curve.
I got values for the graph from a file.

So i must do 3 things in order to animate the graphs:

- read values in the file build some array of object to hold the values
- draw a curve progressively from the read values
- draw one line in other graph from the read values

Each of these task must be repeated every x seconds.
At the moment I'm doing it using a swing timer and a class extending SwingWorker.  In the doInBackground method i read the file, loop through the values to build my object and fill an array.

In the process method I use some the array to build the curve, and in the done method I draw the line.  But the result is not what I intend to do.
The curve is drawing to fast.  For exemple if I execute the timer every 2 seconds then the curve must take 2 seconds from one end of the graph to reach the other end.  Then I must draw one line in the other graph.  At the moment the curve is drawn at once every two seconds.

How can I organize this in different thread if possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to take a look at **[Trident animation library](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)**. It will simplify a lot of this for you.

Comment: Hello it may be a good library, but i don't want to depend on tertiary libraries unless i have no choice.

Comment: It is your choice, but amount of work and knowledge Trident has easily outweighs the time you can spend on animation. I'm sure your goal is to deliver functionality and not create an animation library.

Comment: +1 Trident, and if you *must* reinvent the wheel then I recommend studying that code. It's very well written.

Answer (score 0):

> The curve is drawing to fast. For exemple if i execute the timer every 2 seconds then the curve must take 2 seconds from one end of the graph to reach the other end

Then start a second Timer within the first timer when it fires.

Comment: When the Timer launch i execute the swing worker, that does all three tasks.  Do you mean that i can launch a second timer inside my worker ?